# My app is not appearing in the settings app after I deploy it in my Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, delphi

When I deploy an app from Delphi to my iPhone, I am unable to see the app in the Settings app. I have tried deploying it on different iPhones and iPads, but the same result occurs.

[image]

What did I miss ?

Comment: Have you created `Settings.Bundle` for your application? You may want to check [Persisting Settings in Delphi iOS Applications](https://community.embarcadero.com/article/technical-articles/162-programming/1852-persisting-settings-in-delphi-ios-applications) article from Embarcadero about creating persisting settings for your applications.

Comment: @SilverWarior but why some app are presented in settings app without this settings.bundle but other not ?

Answer (score 5):

An app only appears in the Settings app if any of the following are true:

- Has a Settings.bundle
- Requests any privacy permissions
- Uses notifications
- Uses background app refresh
- Supports Siri search
- Accesses data over the Internet (for the Cellular Data option on devices with Cellular data support)
- In the latest iOS it will appear if the app is localized to more than one language.

If an app doesn't appear in the Settings app then it is not using any of those features.

Comment: My app does LocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization and I grant it the permission with precise location but the app is not appearing in the app settings :( I try on Ipad and Iphone, same result.

Comment: Strange. Certainly asking for and granting location permission should definitely cause an app to appear in the Settings app.

Comment: I agree but it's not what i see :( requesting permission to access the camera for example work and I can see the app in the settings app but not for precise location that very strange :(

Comment: I tried also to acccess data over the internet, nothing change :(